# Stats properties among documents R

Tags: r, statistics, std, text-mining

I have a table, such as:

```
test_data <- data.frame(
  doc = c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3),
  word = c("person", "grand", "person", "moment", "bout", "person", "moment"),
   frenq= c(9,8,5,4,3,5,3))
```

I would like to calculate mean and std for each "word" and create a new table such as.

```
    word   freq (number of docs)  mean    std 
 personn     19                3  6.33  2.309
  moment      7                2  2.33  2.081
```

And the main problem is the sdt, for example, for the word "person" is sd(c(9,5,5)) but the for word "moment" is sd(c(0,4,3)). Zero is the first number because this word is not in the doc 1.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Hi, is it clear now? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `dplyr`.  Create a new dataset ("d1") by the unique combinations of "doc", and "word" columns of "test_data" (`expand.grid(..)`).  Join "d1" with "test_data" (`left_join`), replace the `NA` values in "frenq" by "0" (`replace(frenq,..)`), get the summary statistics using `mutate_each` after grouping by "word".

```
library(dplyr)
d1 <- expand.grid(doc=unique(test_data$doc), word=unique(test_data$word))
res <- left_join(d1, test_data) %>%
                   mutate(frenq=replace(frenq, is.na(frenq), 0)) %>%
                   group_by(word) %>% 
                   summarise_each(funs(freq=sum,NumberOfdocs= sum(.!=0),
                         mean, std=sd), frenq)
  res
  #    word freq Numberofdocs     mean      std
  #1   bout    3            1 1.000000 1.732051
  #2  grand    8            1 2.666667 4.618802
  #3 moment    7            2 2.333333 2.081666
  #4 person   19            3 6.333333 2.309401
```

Or using a similar approach using methods in `data.table`.  Convert "data.frame" to "data.table" (`setDT`), set "doc", "word" as the key columns (`setkey`), crossjoin unique elements of "doc" and "word" (`CJ(doc=...,)`), assign '0' for `NA` elements in "frenq" (`is.na(frenq), frenq:=0`), and get the summary statistics (`list(freq=..)`) grouped by "word".

```
  library(data.table)
  setkey(setDT(test_data), doc, word)[CJ(doc=unique(doc), 
        word=unique(word))][is.na(frenq), frenq:=0][,
           list(freq=sum(frenq), Numberofdocs=sum(frenq!=0), 
                  mean=mean(frenq), std=sd(frenq)) , by = word]
   #    word freq Numberofdocs     mean      std
   #1:   bout    3            1 1.000000 1.732051
   #2:  grand    8            1 2.666667 4.618802
   #3: moment    7            2 2.333333 2.081666
   #4: person   19            3 6.333333 2.309401
```

Comment: The second worked (setkey), not the first one (dplyr).

Comment: @user3810278 No idea why the first one didn't work.  I used `dplyr_0.4.0`

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be to first get list of unique words in your data (d):

```
uw <- unique(d$word)
```

Then you can iterate over `uw` fetching all data matching a word (w):

```
for (w in uw){
    numdoc <- max(d$doc[d$word==w])
    freqs <- d$freq[d$word==w]
    m <- mean(freqs)
    ## etc ...
}
```

I'm sure there is more elegant way using `apply`, but above should give you good idea on how to proceed further.

Comment: Actually my main problem is the sdt, for example, for the word "person" is sd(c(9,5,5)) but the word "moment" is sd(c(0,4,3))...